# Xutuntu 22.04 black screen when `prime-select` is set to `nvidia` or `on-demand`

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I recently migrated my Xubuntu 22.04 setup to a new laptop (Dell Precision 3580). After tinkering around for a few days, the Intel Iris Xe GPU works now. However, I just can't make the Nvidia RTX A500 working.

I am using Xubuntu with lightdm, Linux kernel 6.2.0-26-generic.

I have installed `nvidia-driver-535` from `apt`, and the output of `sudo lshw -C video` show that none of the 2 GPUs are "UNCLAIMED".

However, whenever `prime-select` is set to `nvidia` or `on-demand`, Xubuntu boots into a black screen after unlocking the encrypted drive. At this point, if `prime-select` is set to `nvidia`, I can press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to get a tty, login and use Xubuntu there. However, if `prime-select` is set to `on-demand`, then Ctrl+Alt+F1 has no effect and the machine remains stuck at the black screen.

I added a `10-nvidia-drm-outputclass.conf` to my `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` following [this arch documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NVIDIA_Optimus#Use_NVIDIA_graphics_only).

I also followed the [arch documentation here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NVIDIA_Optimus#LightDM) to add a display setup script to invoke bash

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "hello" > /tmp/hello.txt
xrandr --setprovideroutputsource modesetting NVIDIA-0
xrandr --auto
```

After adding this, Ctrl+Alt+F1 works even if `prime-select` is set to `on-demand`. When Xubuntu boots into a black screen, going to the tty I can see that `/tmp/hello.txt` is created, so the script did run.

I tried to set `options nvidia-drm modeset=0` according to [this nvidia forum reply](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/ubuntu-20-04-boot-to-black-screen-when-selecting-nvidia-as-prime-after-kernel-update/219727/6), but that didn't work.

[This thread on nvidia forum](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/black-screen-with-cursor-when-prime-select-nvidia-ubuntu-20-04-dell-precision-3581-with-nvidia-rtx-a500-laptop-gpu-ga107gl-a/258049) describes a similar symptom on Ubuntu 20.04 and says no issues on Ubuntu 22.04, but I'm already on 22.04. [This reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/openSUSE/comments/rubeqp/nvidia_optimus_black_screen_when_typing_sudo/?rdt=46936) describes a similar problem on openSUSE but I don't see a concrete solution there.

I also tried to make the driver load earlier by embedding it into initrd, as described in [this nvidia reply here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/linux-mint-nvidia-driver-loads-with-startx-but-not-on-initial-startup/168262/2), but that didn't change the outcome.

I also cleaned up all the stale xorg.conf files as suggested in [this nvidia forum thread](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/black-screen-when-strating-display-manager-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-20-04-with-nvidia-drivers-geforce-gtx-950m/160485/4), but that also didn't change the outcome.

At this point I'm out of ideas. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some more tinkering, I finally figured it out. It turns out there were some old config files such as `10-nvidia-brightness.conf` and `10-nvidia.conf` in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` that disrupted the setup. Additionally, the `10-nvidia-drm-outputclass.conf`  file is also not necessary.

After removing all 3 of those config files, now only `10-evdev.conf`, `10-quirks.conf`, `11-nvidia-offload.conf`, `40-libinput.conf`, `70-wacom.conf` are left in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`. In particular, the `11-nvidia-offload.conf` is generated by gpu-manager. This finally got rid of the black screen and now I can use the GUI again.

Hopefully this  helps anyone who face a similar problem.